# Http client gives Target host must not be null error

Tags: android

My code is as shown below:

```
public class YActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 try {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: page response" + getResponseFromUrl("www.iammjet.in"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public String getResponseFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create HTTP Client
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL); // Set the action you want to do
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // Executeit
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the response
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line);

        String resString = sb.toString();

        is.close();
        return resString;
    }


}
```

Now what happens here is it gives me `Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=www.iammjet.in`  error , what should I insert to make it work?

I am using compileSdkVersion 24. To support HttpClient I have added in my build.gradle as follows:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

My error stack trace is as shown below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{demand.inn.com.xyz.staging/demand.inn.com.xyz.activity.YActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
                                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
                                                                                    at demand.inn.com.quflip.activity.YActivity.getResponseFromUrl(YActivity.java:328)
                                                                                    at demand.inn.com.quflip.activity.QuFlipActivity.onCreate(QuFlipActivity.java:94)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 


                                                                                --------- beginning of crash
```

Comment: Try adding `http://` before the URL

Comment: Also this is an old way to do http on android and is (sadly) no longer supported. Which version of android are you building for?

Comment: complieSdkVersion 24    buildToolsVersion 25.0.1

Comment: `HttpClient` doesn't exist under sdk 24.  You're going to need to edit a little more detail into your question.  Where did you get `HttpClient` (have you added a dependency to your gradle script?)

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three major problems with your code:

1. Your URL is badly formatted (giving the error)
2. You are doing [networking on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)
3. The client library you are trying to use is being removed from later versions of android. Use an [URLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) if you can.

**Formatting your URL**

Your browser lies to you.  `www.iammjet.in` is not an URL.  It's just a host name.  To be an URL you MUST have a scheme, host and path (as the error tells you.

`http://www.iammjet.in/` is valid.  It has the scheme `http`, host `www.iammjet.in` and path `/`.  Because you have given it just the hostname it's misinterpreted it to be just the path and said that the hostname is null.

Comment: Have you noticed that `HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);` is not referencing your argument `url` but an entirely different constant called `URL`?

Comment: I even tried with `url` , but still it is not working

Comment: You should edit the full stack trace into your question.  Be clear with the words "still not working" did the error (stack trace) change?

Comment: Good. Now read that stack trace and read poimt 2 of my answer and see if they are related.

Answer (score 0):

pass "http://www.iammjet.in" instead of "www.iammjet.in"

Comment: No, the problem persist

Comment: bcaz your url not open in browser..i think